# Is therea List of unlocked regions for Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a List of regions and countries where pokemon-Go is already unlocked, and/or when certain countries are beeing unlocked?

There are no informations regarding this on the official Pokemon-Go website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Go#Release),

> The game was released in Australia, New Zealand, and the United States on July 6, 2016. Due to server strain from high demand upon release, Niantic CEO John Hanke stated that the release in most other regions was "paused until [Niantic was] comfortable" fixing the issues. On July 13, 2016, Pokémon Go was released in the United Kingdom and Germany for Android devices.

So as of today, it's only those countries. For future reference you can check the releases section on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you. sadly there is nothing about future releases.